# Can I use replace function in Python to replace any characters that are NOT present in a given set?

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to write a program that can take a list of authors' names from a journal paper and edit out all the fluff they include between their names like' Alexander E. Davies,1,2,4, Michael Pargett,1' and return them in the following format: 'Alexander E. Davies; Michael Pargett'.

I know how to use pythons replace function to replace one character with another but how would I use it to remove numbers and not alphabetical characters from a string and add a semi-colon between the names?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use the `re` module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `re`:

```py
import re

s = "Alexander E. Davies,1,2,4, Michael Pargett,1"

s = re.sub(r"(,\s*\d+)+", "", s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
Alexander E. Davies, Michael Pargett
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible using replace function if those numbers are not same everytime.

**If the same numbers(pattern) are repeated**

In this case you can use replace function

```py
a = 'Alexander E. Davies,1,2,4, Michael Pargett,1,2,4,'
b = a.replace(',1,2,4,',';')
print(b)
#outputs
'Alexander E. Davies; Michael Pargett,1'
```

**If numbers/pattern (is)are different**

This is the same as in your example in which we can use regex to replace the characters

```py
import re
rgx = '[0-9,]+'
a = 'Alexander E. Davies,1,2,4, Michael Pargett,1,'
b = re.sub(rgx, ';', a)
print(b)
#outputs
'Alexander E. Davies; Michael Pargett;'
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the + symbol, please? I'm new to python and don't understand its purpose in the above snippet.

Comment: @TomG888 the "rgx" variable is a regular expression which are used to match a pattern inside a string the + sign indicates to match one or more ocurrences of the pattern. So the whole reg expression means that we are matching any digit between 0-9 and a comma (,). To learn more about regular expression you can visit [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that the format is consistent and that commas are the separator between names

```py
original_string = ' Alexander E. Davies,1,2,4, Michael Pargett,1'

# Remove leading and trailing whitespace, and split by comma
split_by_commas = original_string.strip().split(',')
>>> split_by_commas
['Alexander E. Davies', '1', '2', '4', ' Michael Pargett', '1']

# Go through each string in the list of strings. Discard the ones for which `isdigit()` is true
string_without_digits = (char for char in split_by_commas if not char.isdigit())

# Join the resulting strings with `; ` as the separator
seperated_by_semi_colons = '; '.join(string_without_digits)
>>> seperated_by_semi_colons 
'Alexander E. Davies;  Michael Pargett'
```

If there are commas within names then this won't work.

Reference for `string.isdigit`  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit